# SCSS exclude element from common styles and apply class style

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply my .button-orange style to button in 



. So I have global setup as usual **li > a** which conflict and override styles from **.button-orange**  ex.

```
<a class='.button-orange'>
```

I just used

```
li > a:not(.button-orange) { ...styles for exclude }
```

So this works, but I styles from **.button-orange** not fully apply (like background colour not orange) Is there way say use only styles as !important for **a.button-orange** ??

Answer (score 1):

Could have been a typo just in the question, but you probably don't want that dot on the class:

```
<a class='button-orange'>
```

Answer (score 0):

this should overwrite your `li > a` rule if is written after that

```
li > a.button-orange{
    your rules for button
}
```

you can also use `!important` to be sure it will apply, but avoid doing it, if not really needed

Comment: It is but in this case I have to copy paste all from .button-orange{}.

Comment: Also thing like 

              a.button-orange{
             @extend .button-orange;
          }

  makes parser error